# Export/reuse Java 11 "Single-File Source-Code" in-memory class

Tags: java

Java 11 introduced a new feature [JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330), called "Single-File Source-Code Execution".
I was wondering: Do I need a JDK 11 for it or JRE 11 will be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the page you linked](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330)

> Source-file mode requires the presence of the jdk.compiler module.

You're going to need the JDK compiler module to use this new feature.